# Version control of baseline.prof

Tags: android

I'm a beginner of Android developer. I'm confused **how to control the version of baseline.prof on different Android platforms**. for example, if I generate baseline-prof.txt on Android S, and package them as an apk, then I release the apk on Android T, can baseline-prof.txt(baseline.prof) still be available?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If I want to run my app with baseline.prof on different Android platforms, should I build the apk for each platform?